# Order Total and Order Item issue when creating order magento 2

Tags: product, magento-2.1, orders, sales-order, quote

I am using the following to create an order in magento 2. Basically I have to shift data from a custom made eCommerce site to magento 2.

```
protected function createRealOrder($singleOrder, $tempOrder, $customer)
{
    try
    {
        $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore($customer->getStoreId());
        $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($store);

        $quote = $this->_quote->create();
        $quote->removeAllItems();
        $quote->setStoreId($customer->getStoreId());
        $customerMain = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
        $quote->setCurrency();
        $this->_cartRepositoryInterface->save($quote);
        $quote->assignCustomer($customerMain);

        //add items in quote
        if ($singleOrder['details'])
        {
            foreach ($singleOrder['details'] as $singleProduct)
            {

                $product = $this->getProductDetails($singleProduct);
                $quoteItem = $this->_quoteItem->create();
                $quoteItem->setQty($singleProduct['total_items']);
                $quoteItem->setPrice($singleProduct['unit_price']);
                $quoteItem->setAdditionalData(json_encode(array('category_id' => 491)));
                $quoteItem->setQuote($quote);
                $quoteItem->setProduct($product);
                $quote->addItem($quoteItem);
            }
        }

        // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method

        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                ->collectShippingRates()
                ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping'); //shipping method
        $quote->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery'); //payment method
        $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effetc inventory
        // Set Sales Order Payment
        $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'cashondelivery']);

        $this->_cartRepositoryInterface->save($quote);
        $quote->collectTotals();
        // Create Order From Quote
        $quote = $this->_cartRepositoryInterface->get($quote->getId());
        $order = $this->_cartManagementInterface->submit($quote);

        $order->setEmailSent(0);

    } catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        echo '<br/> ' . $e->getCode();
        echo '<br/> ' . $e->getFile();
        echo '<br/> ' . $e->getLine();
        echo '<br/> ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

This does create an order for the assigned customer in the specified store.
Issue comes in the order totals. I get 0 original price for all the order items.

I did check the quote and quote_item database, they are alright, and everything gets calculated fine but when it translates into an order, all the totals are gone from sales_order and sales_order_item [image]

Comment: Any shopping cart rule are enabled ?

Comment: I dont know about that, will that have an effect ? and should i enable or disable them ? and i am quite new to it. can you please let me know how i can do that? Thanks

Comment: please disable all shopping cart rule from backend(marketing > cart price rules) and try to create an order

Comment: I disabled everything, in cart price. and still it did not work